# Values Are Combining

Tags: javascript, ajax

`I have a script that is returning the right values except for one little problem.  Lid is returning 892 which is right, However; Cid which should return 16 its returning 89216 a combination of the two.  How can I get Cid to just return 16?

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{

$(".Doggie").change(function()
{
    var LocationString ='Lid='+ $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_city.php",
        data: LocationString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $(".Kitty").html(html);
        }
    });
});

$('.Kitty').live("change",function(){
    var Lid = $('#Doggie').val(),  // This is the value of the id="Doggie" selected option
    Cid = $(this).val(); // This is the value of the id="Kitty" selected option
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_area.php",
        data: {"Lid":Lid,"Cid":Cid}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {                         
$(".Pig").html(html);
} 
});

});

});
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="frame1">
  <label>Place :</label>
    <select name="Doggie" class="Doggie" id="Doggie">
    <option selected="selected">--Select Place--</option>
        <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT tblLocations.RestID as Lid, tblRestaurants.RestName as name
            FROM tblRestaurants INNER JOIN tblLocations ON tblRestaurants.RestID = tblLocations.RestID
            GROUP BY tblLocations.RestID, tblRestaurants.RestName
            ORDER BY tblRestaurants.RestName ASC");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Lid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            } ?>
         </select>
        <label>City :</label>
        <select name="Kitty" class="Kitty" id="Kitty">
        <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
        </select>
        <label>Area: :</label>
        <select name="Pig" class="Pig" id="Pig">
        <option selected="selected">--Select Area--</option>
        </select>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax_city.php

```
    <?php
require('config.php');

if($_POST['Lid'])
{
$Lid=$_POST['Lid'];
//$Cid=$_POST['Cid'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT tblLocations.RestId as Lid, tblLocations.CityID as Cid, tblCities.CityName as name
            FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN tblCities ON tblLocations.CityID = tblCities.CityID
            WHERE tblLocations.RestID = $Lid
            GROUP BY tblLocations.RestID, tblCities.CityName
            ORDER BY tblCities.CityName ASC");

echo '<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['Lid'].''.$row['Cid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
}

?>
```

ajax_area.php

```
    <?php
require('config.php');

if($_POST['Lid'])
{
//$Lid=$_POST['Lid'];
 $Cid=$_POST['Cid'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT tblLocations.RestId as Lid, tblLocations.CityID as Cid, tblAreas.AreaName as name
            FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN tblAreas ON tblLocations.AreaID = tblAreas.AreaID
            WHERE tblLocations.RestID = $Lid AND tblLocations.CityID = $Cid
            GROUP BY tblLocations.RestID, tblAreas.AreaName
            ORDER BY tblAreas.AreaName ASC");

echo '<option selected="selected">--Select Area--</option>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['Lid'].''.$row['Cid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're doing `Lid + Cid` at some point, and it's performing string concatenation rather than arithmetic addition because the values are stored as strings. There's nothing that does that in the code, but it's the only logical explanation I can come up with.

Comment: I thought maybe it would be here, maybe missing a semi-colon or something?  var Lid = $('#Doggie').val(), Cid = $(this).val();

Comment: That's perfectly valid syntax for declaring multiple variables at the same time, and wouldn't cause the problem you're describing. The code in the question is obviously not complete, though - perhaps you could update the question with the rest of it?

Comment: Updated.  Did you need the php as well?

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer so I'm not sure how much use my seeing it would be. That said, I can't see any obvious issues with the JavaScript, so the error may be server-side; might be a good idea to include it.

Answer (score 0):

It was these two lines in the ajax-city.php file.

```
"SELECT tblLocations.CityId as Cid, tblCities.CityName as name
```

And

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['Cid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```